# Why eval_set is not used in cross_validate with XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, xgboost, cross-validation

I'm trying to plot a graph where I can see the evolution in learning of the model as the number of estimators increases. I can do this with `eval_set` in `xgboost.XGBClassifier`, giving this plot:

[image]

But when I use `cross_validate()`, it ignores the `eval_set` argument. Why? The code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

scores = cross_validate(
    estimator=XGBClassifier(n_estimators=30,
                             max_depth=3,
                             min_child_weight =4,
                             random_state=42,
                           eval_set=[(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test)]),
    X=data.drop('Y', axis=1),
    y=data['Y'],
    #fit_params=params, 
    cv=5,
error_score='raise',
    return_train_score=True,
    return_estimator=True
)
```

The warning is: `Parameters: { "eval_set" } are not used.`

How can I do such that `cross_validate` takes the argument of `eval_set`?

Answer (score 0):

`eval_set` determines train and validation data, but cross-validation determines train and validation data in every iteration. To be more concrete, ith fold is used as a validation data and the others are used as train data.
Therefore eval_set is meaningless for cross-validation and remove it.